# Regular expression, can only start with zero or more whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match a string with a regular expression in C#. The string can only be preceeded by zero or more whitespaces, no other characters is allowed.

Valid strings are:

```
"> 5", " > 5"
```

Invalid strings are:

```
"1 > 5", "1> 3", ">> 3"
```

I have this regular expression right now:

```
"\s*> "
```

I have also tried `"[\s*]> "` and `"[\s]*> "` but with no luck.

This seems like a simple problem, but im fresh to regular expressions and i failed to find an answer elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [When asking regex questions, always add the tag for the specific programming language or tool (e.g., Perl, Python, or Java; vi, emacs, or ɢɴᴜ grep; etc.) you are using.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: I'm a bit confused if an expression can start with "zero or more" whitespaces. That means, that it can start with "zero whitespace" which then means that it can start with other characters right?

Comment: Try \s+ though Johnsy is quite correct and some context would be useful.

Comment: You have to anchor the regex. Try "^\s*>" (no quotes), and you probably have to escape the \ in some way (normally by putting \\ )

Comment: Johnsyweb, updated question, C#

Comment: The regex could look something like: ^\s*>\s*\d*$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you simply meant "start with 0 or more whitespace characters", because then **every string** would be valid, including the empty string, because it satisfies at least "start with 0 whitespace".

Looking at your sample input, perhaps you meant "start with 0 or more whitespace characters, followed by exactly one `>`". In that case, this regex should do it:

```
^\s*>[^>]*$
```

Replace the second `*` with a `+` if you need to match stuff after the `>` sign.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i meant, thanks for understanding and sorry for not making it clearer. It seems to work, so i accept this as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Start your expression with `^` to indicate that it is anchored to the start of the string being tested. Otherwise any substring matching the expression will mean the expression counts as matching, and of course every substring starts with zero-or-more whitespace (every substring starts with zero-or-more anything). Hence:

```
^\s*>
```

Likewise, if you want to specify what a string may end with, then use `$` to anchor to the end of the string being tested.

The singleline and multiline options change the behaviour of these anchors in the case of tested expressions containing newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick :

`^\s*>.+?$`

Comment: Not really, the `.` would match a second `>` too which OP doesn't want.

Comment: @BoltChock i have added the ? character

Answer (score 0):

`^\s*>[^>]*$` doesn't match with `'   > 35 > 23'`

`^\s*>(?!>).*$` does match